# How can I retrieve detailed error information from ldapjs?

Tags: javascript, openldap, ldapjs

I'm working in the Ubuntu 20.04 and openLDAP 2.4.49 environment.

How can I retrieve detailed error information from ldapjs?
(ldapjs version is 3.0.5)

For example, if I change the password immediately after changing it once, and then execute the following command:

```
ldappasswd -H ldapi:/// -x -D <myDN> -W -S
```

The result displays detailed information like:

```
Result: Constraint violation (19)
Additional info: Password is too young to change
```

However, when I perform the following code using ldapjs, the result only shows the ConstraintViolationError value without detailed information.

```
'use strict';

const ldap = require('ldapjs');

const client = ldap.createClient({
  socketPath: '/run/ldapi',
});

function changePassword() {
  const userDN = <user_DN>;
  const userPassword = <userPassword>;

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.bind(userDN, userPassword, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      } else {
        const change = new ldap.Change({
          operation: 'replace',
          modification: {
            type: 'userPassword',
            values: ['NewPassword'],
          }
        });

        client.modify(userDN, change, err => {
          if (err) {
            return reject(err);
          }

          return resolve();
        });
      }
    })
  });
}

(async () => {
  try {
    await changePassword();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`${JSON.stringify(e)}`);
  }


  client.unbind();
})();
```

What is the method to obtain detailed information, such as "Password is too young to change," when using ldapjs?

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/ldapjs/node-ldapjs/issues/878) on the repository complaining that, starting from version 3, the errors are not detailed as the previous major version.

At the moment, I have to stick to version 2 in order to be able to get detailed error messages.